# Why does writing to GCS bucket result in local dev blob store entries instead?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I use the Google App Engine Standard environment to develop my Python app using Development SDK 1.9.61.

I'm trying to learn to use Google Cloud Storage in my app by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). I verified that my default and staging buckets do exist via the cloud console, and manually uploaded a sample file to each bucket using my browser.

Next, I programmatically uploaded some files to a bucket (so I thought) via my local development app instance per [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage).

However, when I checked my cloud storage buckets via my GCP Console in my browser, I could not find the files. After searching my local development SDK console, I eventually found the files located in the local "Blobstore Viewer".

I'm confused, based on [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) I expected to find the files in my project's cloud storage bucket.

I searched the [App Engine Python Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/release-notes) for some potential SDK version changes to explain this behavior, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Is this the way it's supposed to work? Are [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload files to a local development server, those exist in-memory on your machine.  The GCP Console doesn't interact with your local development server, it interacts with the public (production) Google Cloud Storage API.

So in essence, the files on your local dev server are in a completely different namespace.  If you want to interact with the production version of Google Cloud Storage and see the results in the GCP console, you'll need to use a non-dev-server deployment of your application.

Comment: I wish the Google documentation reflected this behavior, it would have saved me a lot of time and confusion!